# Show that the subgroup $s(K) \subset H \rtimes_{\alpha} K$ is normal if and only if $\alpha: K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ is the trivial homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that the subgroup $s(K) \subset H \rtimes_{\alpha} K$ is normal if and only if $\alpha: K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ is the trivial homomorphism, where $s : K \rightarrow H \rtimes_{\alpha} K$ is given by $s(k) = (e,k)$.

What's confusing about this question is that $\alpha: K \rightarrow Aut(H)$ is given by $\alpha(k)(h) = khk^{-1}$. So two elements (k and h) are taken to one element in Aut(H), right? In other words, in a regular homomorphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$, we would take one element from X and end up with one element in Y, right? So if we wanted to prove that f was the trivial homomorphism, we would just need to show that, for any $x \in X$, $f(x)=e$. But this question is a bit confusing because we take **two** elements and end up with one. So how is it possible to show that $\alpha(k)(h)$ is the trivial homomorphism? Do I fix h and just change k? Or do I fix k and change h? Or do I not fix anything? In other words, how does one usually deal with these types of homomorphism with more than one element?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both $H$ and $K$ are normal, then you have two normal subgroups such that $HK=KH=G$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$. This is to say that $G=H\times K$. This forces the multiplication in $G$ to be defined as $(h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2)=(h_1h_2,k_1k_2)$, that is, $\alpha=id$.

The converse is trivial.